# Trouble downloading android source

Tags: android, osx-lion

I am using a mac system and while i do a repo sync for downloading the android source. 
I get this error in between. What can i do to solve this issue ?

```
From /Users/ArunAbraham/ANDROID_DIRECTORY/.repo/projects/docs/source.android.com.git/clone.bundle
 * [new branch]      master     -> aosp/master
Downloading device/ti/panda:  68% (17MB/25MB)  error: Couldn't resolve host 'android.googlesource.com' while accessing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/android-mock/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
Downloading device/ti/panda:  76% (19MB/25MB)  error: Couldn't resolve host 'android.googlesource.com' while accessing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
Downloading device/ti/panda:  80% (20MB/25MB)  error: Couldn't resolve host 'android.googlesource.com' while accessing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/android-mock/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
Downloading device/ti/panda:  88% (22MB/25MB)  error: Cannot fetch platform/external/android-mock
```

Comment: No. Android source code. http://source.android.com

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the Using Authentication part in http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.